# Title on the secondary tile is not clear

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a problem about secondary tile. The title of my secondary tile is not obvious on the background image. So I want to add a title background which is a rectangle with the similar size as my title. But how can I do that? I have two ways in my mind.

1. Get my background image from internet, add the title background on it and store it locally. And when I make the tile, I'll use the local url. This method looks kind of overkill. I have to download the image and do some integration. And also I have to store the image locally.
2. Customize the title control, change its foreground. This method looks more elegant. But I'm not sure how I can customize the title in the secondary tile. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is probably what you want. As far as I know, there's very little custmization you can do with the Standard tile class.

I was unhappy with the text for other reasons and ended up doing the equivalent of your 1st suggestion.